# What is the origin of the name term "string"?

Tags: computer-science, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The History Behind the Definition of a 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880195/the-history-behind-the-definition-of-a-string)

Wikipedia doesn't mention anything, and I can't seem to find anything even in some CompSci books from the library.

Answer (score 1):

It is a "string" of characters... old languages used to have difficulty defining a string, it was an array of characters which, when "strung" together, made a word.  I have a feeling that it was simply adapted through obviousness.

Answer (score 0):

It (probably) denotes a string of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I always pictured it having to do with C-style strings, where one char is "strung" together in memory to the next. Like a string of pearls.